# Display a 3D bar graph using transparency and multiple colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataframe where rows represent hours of the day and the columns represent time frequencies. The aim is to create a 3D bar chart and each column represented a different color. My dataframe is as follows

```
frec=pd.read_csv('tiempo.csv', parse_dates='Horas',index_col='Horas')
frec.index=[date.strftime('%H:%M') for date in frec.index]

frec
         Inicio  MaxExt  Fin
18:00       1       1    1
19:00       0       0    3
20:00       1       1    1
21:00       1       1    0
22:00       3       1    0
23:00       9       1    0
00:00       8       3    2
01:00       2       0    1
02:00       3       8    1
03:00       5       3    2
04:00       6       2    6
05:00       6       6    5
06:00       5       6    4
07:00       5       7    2
08:00       2       4    5
09:00       1       6    6
10:00       0       3    2
11:00       2       5    5
12:00       4       1    9
13:00       2       4    2
15:00       0       2    3
14:00       3       2    4
15:00       0       2    3
16:00       1       1    3
17:00       0       2    3
```

The following lines of code trying to create the plot

```
xpos=np.arange(frec.shape[0])
ypos=np.arange(frec.shape[1])
yposM, xposM = np.meshgrid(ypos+0.5, xpos+0.5)
zpos=np.zeros(frec.shape).flatten()

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy= 0.1 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dz=frec.values.ravel()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])
colors = cm.rainbow(values)

ax.bar3d(xposM.ravel(),yposM.ravel(),zpos,dx,dy,dz,color=colors, alpha=0.5)


ticks_x = np.arange(0.5, 24, 1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks_x)
ticks_y=np.arange(0.6,3,1)
ax.set_yticks(ticks_y)

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(frec.index)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(frec.columns)

ax.set_xlabel('Hora')
ax.set_ylabel('B')
ax.set_zlabel('Occurrence')
plt.xticks(ticks_x ['1PM','2PM','3PM','4PM','5PM','6PM','7PM','8PM','9PM','1OPM','11PM','12AM','1AM','2AM','3AM','4AM','5AM','6AM','7AM','9AM','10AM','11AM','12PM'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How I get a plot where each column is drawn with different color ?. Ie, the bars of Inicio column are blue, the bars of MaxExt column are red and the bars of Fin column are yellow

Answer (score 3):

create `colors` by following method:

```
values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., frec.shape[0])
cmaps = [cm.Blues, cm.Reds, cm.Greens]
colors = np.hstack([c(values) for c in cmaps]).reshape(-1, 4)
```

Here is the output:

[image]